# React: How can I route to another page, for example './login' and './sign_up' as whole page

Tags: reactjs, web

```
import Sign from './sign.js'`
import Login from './login.js'    
import {BrowserRouter, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends React.Component{
render(){
return( 
<BrowserRouter>
    <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
    <Link to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>

<Route exact path="/login" >
       <Login />
</Route>
<Route path="/signup">
       <Signup />
</Route>
</BrowserRouter>
)}}
export default App;
```

So my problem is, Upon compiling this code, it only loads the children component. But can you help me to understand that how can I load whole page instead of loading these components into same page.

I tried these methods though.
 1. Tried to make a new page which loads these two pages, such as login and sign up. But that leaves me with two links, which I do not want.
 2. I tried changing the links using above method from each    component, and loads the page in parent app. But it gave me error of computed match.

Please I am a new learner, help me out.

Answer (score -1):

The earlier version of React had this bug, on updating the link. The previous version was not refreshing the page.